# How to do countifs() function of multiple columns in R (count the text values)

Tags: r, text, dplyr, countif

I want to group by users and count the number of where order_hour_type is "daytime" and "evening", and expressed in two columns named "daytime" and "evening" respectively, grouped by users.

```
user_id  order_hour_type order_day_type
1         daytime            weekend
1         daytime            weekday
1         daytime            weekday
1         daytime            weekend
2         evening            weekday
2         evening            weekday
2         evening            weekend
2         daytime            weekday
3         daytime            weekday
3         evening            weekday
3         daytime            weekday
```

And the result should be like this:

```
user_id daytime evening weekend weekday
1         4       0        2       2
2         1       3        1       3
3         2       1        0       3
```

I have tried to use the package `dplyr` with following code:

(take adding the "daytime" column as an example)

```
agg1 <- df %>%
  group_by(user_id,order_hour_type) %>%
  summarise(
    daytime = sum(order_hour_type == "daytime"),
  )
```

and the result is weird with only one user:

```
> head(agg1)
  daytime
1  834149
```

how can I do to generate my expected results? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to `gather` into 'long' format, then do a `count` on the columns and `spread` it back to 'wide'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
gather(df1, key, val, -user_id) %>% 
    count(user_id, val) %>%
    spread(val, n, fill = 0)
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#  user_id daytime evening weekday weekend
#    <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1       1       4       0       2       2
#2       2       1       3       3       1
#3       3       2       1       3       0
```

---

or using `melt/dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(df1), id.var = 'user_id'), user_id ~ value, length)
```

---

A `base R` option would be to replicate the first column by the number of other columns while `unlist`ing the other columns and use `table`

```
table(rep(df1[,1], 2), unlist(df1[-1]))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(user_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), order_hour_type = c("daytime", "daytime", "daytime", 
"daytime", "evening", "evening", "evening", "daytime", "daytime", 
"evening", "daytime"), order_day_type = c("weekend", "weekday", 
"weekday", "weekend", "weekday", "weekday", "weekend", "weekday", 
"weekday", "weekday", "weekday")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But actually my data source is a csv file with more than 100,000 rows (60,000 users). Are the code available in this case?

Comment: @fridaguo  If memory is not a constraint for you, it should work

Comment: Warning message:
In melt.data.table(setDT(df), id.var = "user_id") :
  'measure.vars' [order_hour_type, order_hour_of_day] are not all of the same type. By order of hierarchy, the molten data value column will be of type 'character'. All measure variables not of type 'character' will be coerced too. Check DETAILS in ?melt.data.table for more on coercion.

Comment: do I need to convert the values in df as characters?

Comment: @fridaguo  It s not an error, a warning message which says that both columns are different type.  It is not an issue.  If you want to remove the warning, please convert the columns to `character` ie. 2nd and 3rd column i.e. `df[2:3] <- lapply(df[2:3], as.character)`